# How can I print only 4 digits after decimal in Jmeter using Beanshell post processor?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I just want the output to be rounded off up to 4 decimal places

```
n1 = 904.56
n2 = 20.46
```

```
float a = ${n1} / $(n2};
float b = 0;
log.info(a + "");
b = a;
vars.putObject("b" , a);
log.info( b )
```

***OUTPUT***

```
BeanShellTestElement : 44.211143
BeanShellTestElement : 44.211143
```

***EXPECTED OUTPUT***

```
BeanShellTestElement : 44.2111
BeanShellTestElement : 44.2111
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need string representation - try [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

[image]

For the numeric representation go for [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class:

```
new BigDecimal(a).round(4)
```

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/) so consider migrating.